# How to set up a table with a recursive foreign key and a relationship declaratively in SQLAlchemy?

Tags: python, foreign-keys, sqlalchemy, foreign-key-relationship

Suppose I have a table "nodes" where I store a tree. Each node has a primary key id and a column parent_id.
Of course, I want to access a parent attribute of each node instance, that is, a relation.
One might try:

```
import sqlalchemy, sqlalchemy.orm, sqlalchemy.ext.declarative
engine = sqlalchemy.create_engine('sqlite:///PATHTOMYDATABASE', echo=True)
Base = sqlalchemy.ext.declarative.declarative_base()
class Node(Base):
    __tablename__ = "nodes"
    id = sqlalchemy.Column(sqlalchemy.Integer, primary_key=True) 
    parent_id = sqlalchemy.Column(sqlalchemy.Integer, sqlalchemy.ForeignKey("nodes.id"))
    parent = sqlalchemy.orm.relationship("Node", backref=sqlalchemy.orm.backref("childs"))
Base.metadata.create_all(engine)
```

But when I do that, I get an error:

`sqlalchemy.exc.InvalidRequestError: Table 'nodes' is already defined for this MetaData instance.  Specify 'useexisting=True' to redefine options and columns on an existing Table object.`

I don't understand at what point I could set that option `'useexisting=True'`. Is this the right way?

EDIT: In fact, the error comes indirectly from another part of the original script. If one replaces the database path by the temporary database `:memory:`, it works without problems. Thanks to TokenMacGuy.

So the above example can be considered as a working example.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For some reason, you already have a class registered for that table, or you have defined the table (possibly indirectly) twice.  This happens to me most frequently when I'm experimenting on the python command line; sqlalchemy remembers the table definitions and class mappings longer than is immediately obvious (from the lifetime of the actual MetaData instance).  Make sure you are defining the table *only once* (exit out of the python interpreter and restart it, if you are in one).  Other causes why they might be already present is from table reflection, or something has called `reload()` without really clearing out `sys.modules` first.

If you are using table reflection, you pass the `useexisting=True` option to the declarative extension in the `__table_args__` class variable:

```
class Node(Base):
    __tablename__ = "nodes"
    __table_args__ = {"useexisting": True}
```

But only do that if you are *sure* that you are defining the table intentionally before you define the python class.

If none of these seem to fix the problem, please reduce your module to a minimal example that shows the problem and then post the whole thing in your answer.

Comment: Thank you! Indeed it seems that when creating the minimal example, it works. I will track down my mistake first.

Comment: You're right, my problem was using `metadata.reflect(engine)` before defining the table. This works as long as no `Column` definitions are made inside of the declaration of `Node`. I should probably leave out `metadata.reflect(engine)` if the `Node` declaration contains columns.

Comment: You can use table reflection if you like.  The main reason you would want to use a column definition in addition to reflection is because reflection gets some of the details wrong; you might want a `tinyint` column to be a boolean, or (most commonly) specify foreign key constraints on MySQL MyISAM tables.