# Flask-Blogging error Table is already defined

Tags: python, flask, flask-sqlalchemy

I'm using a flask setup from a while and now trying to install Flask-Blogging module on it. Current modules:
- Flask-sqlalchemy with postgres
- Flask-login
- Flask-Blogging (new)

My application.py looks like this:

```
from flask import Flask
from flask import session
from flask.ext.blogging import SQLAStorage, BloggingEngine
from flask.ext.login import LoginManager
from flask.ext.sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy

'''
The main application setup. The order of things is important
in this file.
'''
app = Flask(__name__)
app.config.from_object('config.base')
app.config.from_envvar('APP_CONFIG_FILE')

'''
Initialize database
'''
db = SQLAlchemy(app)


'''
Initialize blogger
'''
storage = SQLAStorage(db=db)
blog_engine = BloggingEngine(app, storage)
```

the last two lines are the only new things I added (other than the imports). Suddenly now I'm getting error about duplicate table names:

```
sqlalchemy.exc.InvalidRequestError: Table 'customer' is already defined for this MetaData instance.  Specify 'extend_existing=True' to redefine options and columns on an existing Table object.
```

Any ideas what am I doing wrong? I couldn't find much documentation about Flask-Blogging other than:
http://flask-blogging.readthedocs.org/en/latest/

Comment: Have a try to delete `customer` table.

Comment: even if that works in development, i cannot afford to do that in prod. Any other solutions?

Comment: Check the answer here. It may help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7191758/how-to-set-up-a-table-with-a-recursive-foreign-key-and-a-relationship-declarativ

Comment: Is `customer` the only table you're getting errors on?

Comment: No I'm getting errors on all tables. The solution provided by Josh works but I'm scared of using the flag globally:  __table_args__ = {"useexisting": True}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You get this error because in `SQLAStorage.__init__` there is this line:

```
self._metadata.reflect(bind=self._engine)
```

This will look at your database and create sqlalchemy table things for **all** the tables currently in your database.

Thus if your database contains a table called 'customer' the line in your code:

```
storage = SQLAStorage(db=db)
```

will automatically model an sqlalchemy table called 'customer' for you.

Now... no doubt you have your own database model definitions somewhere, probably in another python module, something like:

```
class Customer(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    ...
```

Since this class definition defines a table called 'customer' and since `SQLAStorage` has already defined a table called 'customer' you get the exception as soon as your class `Customer` is imported.

Some ways to work around this problem are:

### Import your database definition modules before instantiating `SQLAStorage`

```
'''
Initialize database
'''
db = SQLAlchemy(app)
import ankit.db_models # import my db models here so SQLAStorage doesn't do it first 

'''
Initialize blogger
'''
storage = SQLAStorage(db=db)
blog_engine = BloggingEngine(app, storage)
```

or

### Tell `SQLAStorage` to use its own metadata

By passing the `db` param to `SQLAStorage.__init__` you are telling it to use your metadata. You can instead just pass the `engine` parameter and it will create its own metadata.

```
storage = SQLAStorage(engine=db.engine)
```

Comment: Thanks for a detailed answer. Are there any drawbacks if this blogger uses it's own metadata?

Comment: Sure, yes, especially if you want to use something like a db migration system... or anything that assumes the metadata to be accurate really.